# Problem extracting equiv-text in XLIFF files with ng extract-i18n on a nx monorepo

Tags: angular, internationalization, nrwl-nx

I'm having some problem troubleshooting a bug with Angular ng extract-i18n on @nrwl/nx 13/ Angular 13. The bug is probably related to source maps on build.

When I run ng extract-i18n, in the generated xlf file, the "equiv-text" attribute of INTERPOLATION and ICU tokens is wrong.  The interpolation equiv-text value is always `equiv-text="&quot;\uFFFD0\uFFFD&quot;"` and for ICU, it is `equiv-text="icu_#"` where # is a number.

For instance, the main extracted string from this:

```html
<ng-container i18n
    >{{ nbHiddenToasts }} older {nbHiddenToasts, plural, =1{message}
    other{messages}} hidden</ng-container
  >
```

is this:

```xml
<source><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="&quot;\uFFFD0\uFFFD&quot;"/> older <x id="ICU" equiv-text="i18n_2"/> hidden</source>
```

I have the problem when running extract-i18n on the application and the i18n text is inside a library.  When I move the text directly inside the app, there is no problem.

I tried updating my application, which did not solve the problem.  I tried to create a minimal Angular app with a lazy loaded library, but could not reproduce the problem in it.

Seeing that, I wonder what configuration to try / how to drill down further in the problem to diagnose what is causing it.

Did any of you have a similar experience and know what is causing it ? Alternately, do anyone have an idea where I should look to be able to pinpoint the bug (what in nx configurations or angular.json configurations could affect sourcemaps, for instance)?